# C# multithreaded program hangs when doing multiple audio sample collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, naudio

Good evening guys,
I have issue with multithreading. I'm doing multiple audio samples collection using a parallel.foreach. I want to be able to do the collection simultaneously. I'm doing a sort of a producer consumer pattern. But the producer section, which is the audio samples collection is hanging soft of.

In each of the parallel threads:

1. A blocking collection is created to collect audio samples
2. A progress bar is created to monitor mic input
3. Lastly a Record function for recording/collecting audio input

I created a blocking collection array for each process, and using naudio WaveInEvent for recording from mic.

The challenge i'm facing is that

1. The program does not resume when I minimize the window
2. Sometimes the program hangs, other times it takes a while before hanging, but overall, the responsiveness is not good at all (Jerky)
   Apart from all these the program is working fine.

What can I do for better performance.

Please check my code below. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using NAudio.Wave;

public partial class frmAudioDetector : Form
{
    //static BlockingCollection<AudioSamples> realtimeSource;
    BlockingCollection<AudioSamples>[] realtimeSource;
    static WaveInEvent waveSource;
    static readonly int sampleRate = 5512;

    private void frmAudioDetector_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            TabControl.TabPageCollection pages = tabControl1.TabPages;
            
            //Tabs pages.Count is 8
            List<int> integerList = Enumerable.Range(0, pages.Count).ToList();

            //Parallel.foreach for simultaneous threads at the same time
            Parallel.ForEach<int>(integerList, i =>
            {
                realtimeSource[i] = new BlockingCollection<AudioSamples>();

                var firstProgressBar = (from t in pages[i].Controls.OfType<ProgressBar>()
                                        select t).FirstOrDefault();

                var firstEmptyComboBox = (from c in pages[i].Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()
                                          select c).FirstOrDefault();

                int deviceNum = firstEmptyComboBox.SelectedIndex;
                
                //create a separate task for each tab for recording    
                _ = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RecordMicNAudio(deviceNum, firstProgressBar, i));
            });                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    
    //Record audio or store audio samples
    void RecordMicNAudio(int deviceNum, ProgressBar progressBar, int t)
    {            
        waveSource = new WaveInEvent();
        waveSource.DeviceNumber = deviceNum;
        waveSource.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(rate: sampleRate, bits: 16, channels: 1);
        waveSource.DataAvailable += (_, e) =>
        {
            // using short because 16 bits per sample is used as input wave format                
            short[] samples = new short[e.BytesRecorded / 2];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(e.Buffer, 0, samples, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            // converting to [-1, +1] range
            float[] floats = Array.ConvertAll(samples, (sample => (float)sample / short.MaxValue));
            //collect realtime audio samples
            realtimeSource[t].Add(new AudioSamples(floats, string.Empty, sampleRate));

            //Display volume meter in progress bar below
            float maxValue = 32767;
            int peakValue = 0;
            int bytesPerSample = 2;
            for (int index = 0; index < e.BytesRecorded; index += bytesPerSample)
            {
                int value = BitConverter.ToInt16(e.Buffer, index);
                peakValue = Math.Max(peakValue, value);
            }

            var fraction = peakValue / maxValue;
            int barCount = 35;

            if (progressBar.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Action action = () => progressBar.Value = (int)(barCount * fraction);
                this.BeginInvoke(action);
            }
            else progressBar.Value = (int)(barCount * fraction);
        };
        waveSource.RecordingStopped += (_, _) => Debug.WriteLine("Sound Stopped! Cannot capture sound from device...");
        waveSource.BufferMilliseconds = 1000;
        waveSource.StartRecording();
    }

  }
```

Comment: And if you don't update the progressBar?

Comment: Seeing a parallel foreach in the Load handler seems to me like the wrong design.  You should design so that your Load handler returns ASAP to keep your application responsive.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. The reason for putting it there was because the recording needs to start as soon as the program loads. Any suggestions how the flow can go?

Comment: Hi @David Browne, the progressBar is to indicate to the user that there's mic input. I would have used a timer, but that's even worse

Comment: I understand that.  But does eliminating the progress bar make the problem go away?  If so can you update it less frequently or have fewer threads updating progress bars?

Comment: One suggestion and addtion to David Browne,  when you use parallel for each, pr default it will use all accessible threads in CPU, this means your computer performance might slow down because all threads become occupied. My suggestion is to use MaxDegreeOfParallelism to limit the threads to like 75% as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939504/sending-5000-messages-in-async-way-in-c-sharp/47946028#47946028 If that helps let me know. so I can make official answer.

Comment: Ok @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I will remove the progress bars and check the performance and get back. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @MaythamFahmi, I'm thinking of removing the parallel foreach, but I'm short of ideas on what else to use. However, I will follow your suggestion and also check the link. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok guys, my discovery based on suggestions. After removing the progress bar, there was no changes, so I applied parallel options, still no changes. Then following @Wyck's advice, I removed the code from the form load and put it in the form constructor. And wow there was significant changes. No more hanging. The only challenge now is the minimize issue. I have to be using switch to in task manager to get back to the program. More help still needed guys. Thanks

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` will block until it's finished, you need to move to a `async` consumer design

Comment: 5512 is a poor sample rate for audio.  Curious choice.

Comment: You cannot access, update, or create and UI element in a non-UI thread. Until you separate out those parts your code will cause you grief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access `pages[i].Controls` from a non-UI thread (e.g. a threadpool threat that will come from Parallel.ForEach) seems wrong.
The NAudio object already uses event driven programming (you provide a `DataAvailable` handler and `RecordingStopped` handler) So there's no need to do that setup work in parallel or in any thread other than the main UI thread.

I would not invoke the volume indicator (progress bar) update directly from the `DataAvailable` handler.  Rather I'd update the control on a `Timer` tick, and just update a shared variable in the `DataAvailable` handler.  This is event driven programming -- there are no threads or tasks are required that I can see apart from the ones that are already used by the wave source IO threads.

e.g.: Use a variable with a simple lock.  Access to this data must be governed with a lock because the `DataAvailable` handler will be invoked on an IO thread to store the current volume, but the value read on the UI thread by the Timer Tick handler, which you can update at a modest rate, certainly no faster than your screen refresh rate.  4 or 5 times per second is likely frequently enough.  Your `BufferMilliseconds` is already 1000 milliseconds (one second) so you may only be getting sample buffers once per second anyway.

#### Form-level fields

```cs
object sharedAccess = new object();
float sharedVolume;
```

#### WaveInEvent DataAvailable handler

```cs
lock (sharedAccess) {
   sharedVolume= ...;
}
```

#### Timer Tick handler

```cs
int volume = 0;
lock(sharedAccess) {
   volume = sharedVolume;
}
progressBar.Value = /* something based on...*/ volume;
```

Goals:

1. do a little work as possible in all event handlers on the UI thread.
2. do as little work as possible in the IO threads (`WaveInEvent.DataAvailable` handler).
3. minimize synchronization between threads when it must occur (try to block the other thread for the least amount of time possible).

With the volume meter out of the way, I'm similarly suspicious about how `BlockingCollection` coordinates access when calling `realtimeSource[t].Add(new AudioSamples(floats, string.Empty, sampleRate));`  Who is *reading* from this collection?  There is contention here between the IO thread on which the bytes are arriving and whatever thread may be consuming these samples.

If you are just recording the samples and don't need to use them until recording is complete, then you don't need any kind of special synchronization or blocking collection to accumulate each buffer into a collection.  You can just add the buffers into a traditional List - provided you don't access it from any other threads until recording is completed.  There may be overhead in managing access to that blocking collection that you don't need to incur.

I get a little nervous when I see all the format conversion you've done:

- from incoming buffer to array of shorts
- from array of shorts to array of floats
- from array of floats to AudioSamples object
- from incoming buffer to Int16 during the volume computation (Why not use re-use your array of shorts?)

Seems like you could cut out a buffer copy here by going directly from the incoming format to the array of floats, and perform your volume computation on the array of floats or on a pinned pointer to the original buffer data in unsafe mode.

Comment: Hi @Wyck, thanks a lot for the analysis. Actually I'm new to multithreading and don't know too many laws, but I'm getting by little by little. I excluded the consuming part, because it was not giving any issues, its actually doing what its intended to do.  It takes from the audio samples in the  blocking collection to perform a form of checking, It runs on a separate thread, and I also implemented it in the parallel foreach. I will implement your suggestions and give you feedback. Thanks

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention. There are 8 tab pages, and each one is supposed to be doing the samples collection. That was the reason for the blocking collection array. One for each tab. The consuming section targets each realtimeSource[t] for its input. For the 5512 sample rate, that's the requirement of the library doing the consuming. I will correct the array of shorts mess. My question is as per including the timer, do I need to use 8 timers or I can re-use one, or how do I go about it. Thanks

Comment: A single timer should do it for the volume meters.  If each realtimeSource is writing to its own collection, then it doesn't need to be a BlockingCollection.  You only need a BlockingCollection if two or more threads will be accessing the same object.  And only if they are doing so in an otherwise unsynchronized way - we can always make arrangements for external synchronization.  e.g. don't read the buffers until recording is complete.